# logits and label must be same size

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to make a custom network to train ck+48 but I got error logits and labels must be broadcastable.

Here my network codes:

def getModel(traing, input_shape = (48,48,3)):

```
  model = models.Sequential()
  
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
  
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
  
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
  
  model.add(layers.Flatten())
  model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='softmax'))
  model.add(layers.Dense(len(set(traing.classes))))
  print(model.summary())
 
  opt    = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(learning_rate=4e-5, epsilon=1e-6)
  loss   = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)#BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True) #False 
  metric = tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')#BinaryAccuracy('accuracy')

  model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=loss, metrics=[metric])

  return model
```

I read all datas with this function:

```
def getData(foldername, train_size=0.1, seed=1):
      data = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=train_size, rescale = 1./255)
      train_generator = data.flow_from_directory( folder_name, 
                                                    target_size = (48, 48), 
                                              batch_size=64, 
                                              subset='training',
                                              seed=seed)
      valid_generator = data.flow_from_directory( folder_name, 
                                              target_size = (48, 48), 
                                              batch_size=64, 
                                              subset='validation',
                                              seed=seed,
                                              shuffle=False)

      
      return train_generator, valid_generator

"""
folderName = CK+48
structure
-CK+48
  -angry
    -image1
    -image2
  -suprised
  -disgust

"""
```

to start training:

```
history =   model.fit(train_generator,
                            steps_per_epoch  = train_generator.n // train_generator.batch_size,
                            epochs=500,
                            )
```

and the summary

```
Found 887 images belonging to 7 classes.
Found 94 images belonging to 7 classes.
Model: "sequential_10"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_50 (Conv2D)          (None, 46, 46, 64)        1792      
                                                                 
 conv2d_51 (Conv2D)          (None, 44, 44, 64)        36928     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_20 (MaxPoolin  (None, 22, 22, 64)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_52 (Conv2D)          (None, 20, 20, 64)        36928     
                                                                 
 conv2d_53 (Conv2D)          (None, 18, 18, 64)        36928     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_21 (MaxPoolin  (None, 9, 9, 64)         0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_54 (Conv2D)          (None, 7, 7, 64)          36928     
                                                                 
 flatten_10 (Flatten)        (None, 3136)              0         
                                                                 
 dense_19 (Dense)            (None, 64)                200768    
                                                                 
 dense_20 (Dense)            (None, 7)                 455       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 350,727
Trainable params: 350,727
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

the error

```
InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[1375,7] labels_size=[55,7]
     [[node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py:5010)
]] [Op:__inference_train_function_16550]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits:
In[0] categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits/Reshape:   
In[1] categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits/Reshape_1:
```

I searched this error in internet and especially stackoverflow, there are a lot of this type error, but I could not solve the problem.

Thanks for helps.

Comment: I changed but got error again, `InvalidArgumentError:  required broadcastable shapes
  [[node Equal
 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py:3567)
]] [Op:__inference_train_function_27344]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node Equal:
In[0] ArgMax: 
In[1] ArgMax_1:`

Comment: Why are you compiling your model with different parameters twice?

Comment: @AloneTogether I would use same compile methods tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 and another networks. I just tried to change layers, instead of vgg19, inceptionv3... And it would work even at the same dataset.

Comment: @AloneTogether I realized it just before comment and fixed but does not work again.

Comment: Update your question then?

Comment: I got this error now, `InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [1600,7] and labels shape [448]
  [[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits
 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py:5114)
]] [Op:__inference_train_function_32938]`

Comment: Show how you create your dataset in your question

Comment: @AloneTogether, Okay, I will edit the question.

Comment: @AloneTogether I edited the question with more detail.

Comment: @AloneTogether, Thanks for your helps, I solved the problem. Problem caused because of my miswriting, I use google colab, and I edited the image shapes but did not run. Because I did not run, input shape was 160,160 but it should be 48,48